# java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException while showing native ads

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-audience-network

I'm showing native ads from audience network in my feed. I'm getting crash below. Anyone knows how to solve it what cause this?

> Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task android.os.AsyncTask$3@2c45c538 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1d1c3911[Running, pool size = 9, active threads = 9, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 757]
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2011)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:793)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1339)
>          at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:594)
>          at com.facebook.ads.internal.util.g.a(Unknown Source)
>          at com.facebook.ads.internal.e.d.a(Unknown Source)
>          at com.facebook.ads.internal.e.d.a(Unknown Source)
>          at com.facebook.ads.internal.g.g.a(Unknown Source)
>          at com.facebook.ads.internal.g.g.c(Unknown Source)
>          at com.facebook.ads.internal.util.ak.j(Unknown Source)
>          at com.facebook.ads.internal.util.ad$6.a(Unknown Source)
>          at com.facebook.ads.internal.util.ad$6.a(Unknown Source)
>          at com.facebook.ads.internal.g.r.b(Unknown Source)
>          at com.facebook.ads.internal.g.r.a(Unknown Source)
>          at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.o.a(Unknown Source)
>          at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.d.c.b.setVideoState(Unknown Source)
>          at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.d.c.b.onCompletion(Unknown Source)
>          at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:3392)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Answer (score 1):

Your code, and the code in your libraries, are starting too many simultaneous `AsyncTask` instances. The default `ThreadPoolExecutor` has a 128-element queue, to go along with the instances that are executing. You have exceeded the capacity of this queue.